# DropDownListFor в режиме Edit при создании приложения в ASP.net не сохраняет значения

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework, mvc

Интегрирована база данных в asp.net. Суть в том, что есть две сущности АЗС и Поставщик, и одна , то есть АЗС имеет внешний ключ на поставщик. Дело в том, что у меня есть выпадающий список при создании новой записи в Азс, выбираю кто будет поставщик, и выбираю через выпадающий список, то есть там отображаются имена поставщиков вместо id. Но! Все хорошо работает и сохраняется при создании, но при редактирования уже существующей записи, значение всегда остается старыми! Как решить эту проблему?

Контроллер:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ASPAzs.Models;

namespace ASPAzs.Controllers
{
public class AzsController : Controller
{
    private AzsContext db = new AzsContext();

    // GET: Azs
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //подгружаем поставщика для отображения в базе данных
        var azs = db.Azss.Include(p => p.postavshik);
        return View(azs.ToList());
    }

    // GET: Azs/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        //Azs azs = db.Azss.Find(id);
        Azs azs = db.Azss.SingleOrDefault(m => m.IdAzs == id);
        if (azs == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(azs);
    }

    // GET: Azs/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        // Формируем список для передачи в представление
        SelectList postav = new SelectList(db.Postavshiks, "IdPostavshika", "ImaPostavshika");
        ViewBag.postav = postav;


        // Формируем список для передачи в представление
        SelectList sotrudnik = new SelectList(db.Sotrudnikis, "IdSotrudnika", "Adress");
        ViewBag.sotrudnik = sotrudnik;

        return View();
    }

    // POST: Azs/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "IdPostavshika,IdSotrudnika,IdAzs,FamiliaDirectora")] Azs azs)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Azss.Add(azs);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(azs);
    }

    // GET: Azs/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {

        // Формируем список для передачи в представление
        SelectList sotrudnik = new SelectList(db.Sotrudnikis, "IdSotrudnika", "Adress");
        ViewBag.sotrudnik = sotrudnik;

        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        //Azs azs = db.Azss.Find(id);
        Azs azs = db.Azss.SingleOrDefault(m => m.IdAzs == id);
        if (azs == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        // Формируем список для передачи в представление
        SelectList postav = new SelectList(db.Postavshiks, "IdPostavshika", "ImaPostavshika");
        ViewBag.postav = postav;
        return View(azs);
    }

    // POST: Azs/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "IdPostavshika,IdSotrudnika,IdAzs,FamiliaDirectora")] Azs azs)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(azs).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.postav = new SelectList(db.Postavshiks, "IdPostavshika", "ImaPostavshika", azs.IdPostavshika);

        return View(azs);
    }

    // GET: Azs/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        //Azs azs = db.Azss.Find(id);
        Azs azs = db.Azss.SingleOrDefault(m => m.IdAzs == id);
        if (azs == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(azs);
    }

    // POST: Azs/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        //Azs azs = db.Azss.Find(id);
        Azs azs = db.Azss.SingleOrDefault(m => m.IdAzs == id);
        db.Azss.Remove(azs);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
}
```

Здесь мой Edit View

```
@model ASPAzs.Models.Azs

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Изменить</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Авто-заправочная станция</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IdPostavshika)

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IdSotrudnika)

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IdAzs)

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="FamiliaDirectora" class="control-label col-md-2">Фамилия директора</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FamiliaDirectora, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FamiliaDirectora, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="IdSotrudnika" class="control-label col-md-2">Сотрудник (задается по уникальному адрессу проживания)</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IdSotrudnika, ViewBag.sotrudnik as SelectList)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdSotrudnika, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">      
        <label for="IdPostavshika" class="control-label col-md-2">Поставщик</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IdPostavshika, ViewBag.postav as SelectList)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdPostavshika, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Вернуться обратно", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Модель поставщика

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ASPAzs.Models
{
    public class Postavshik
    {
        [Key]
        public int IdPostavshika { get; set; }
        public string ImaPostavshika { get; set; }
        public string UridAdress { get; set; }
        public Int64 Inn { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Модель Азс

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ASPAzs.Models
{
    public class Azs
    {
        public string FamiliaDirectora { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public int IdPostavshika { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public int IdSotrudnika { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int IdAzs { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("IdPostavshika")]
        public Postavshik postavshik { get; set; }
    }
}
```

А здесь все работает, то есть сохраняется нормально

```
@model ASPAzs.Models.Azs

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Создание";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Создание</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Авто-заправочная станция</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdPostavshika, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })*@
            <label for="IdPostavshika" class="control-label col-md-2">Поставщик</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.IdPostavshika, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IdPostavshika, ViewBag.postav as SelectList)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdPostavshika, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="IdSotrudnika" class="control-label col-md-2">Сотрудник (задается по уникальному адрессу проживания)</label>
            @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdSotrudnika, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })*@
            @*@Html.LabelForModel("Адресс сотрудника который может работать в АЗС")*@
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.IdSotrudnika, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IdSotrudnika, ViewBag.sotrudnik as SelectList)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdSotrudnika, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.FamiliaDirectora, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })*@
            <label for="FamiliaDirectora" class="control-label col-md-2">Фамилия директора</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FamiliaDirectora, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FamiliaDirectora, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Вернуться обратно", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: пробовали делать проверку на постбэк?

Comment: Что я там должен увидеть?

Comment: скорее всего вы не проверяете страницу на постбэк, и следовательно просто переписываете значение которое было внесено, кроме того проверьте что .DropDownList, вообще отсылает свой постбэк.

Comment: Я Вас не совсем понимаю, что означает проверить страницу на postback. Кроме выпадающих списков есть строка, фамилия директора, она сохраняется отлично, выпадающий список не сохраняется, в нем причина. Куда мне копать? Как проверить на постбэк?

Comment: `Page.IsPostBack()` - на сколько я помню так. и добавить к дроплисту `DropDownList.PostBack=true;`

Comment: Решение нашел, оказалось что вот HiddenFor во view не позволял отослать значения, и значения оставались старыми

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Перекопал весь интернет и нашел решение, которое помогло.
Дело в том, что в view edit есть следующие строки:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IdPostavshika)

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IdSotrudnika)

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IdAzs)
```

Убираем все кроме @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IdAzs), так как ее редактировать мы не собираемся. В результате все отправляется, и в базу сохраняется. Если эти строки будут, то результат остается прежним. Причем, если Вам после этого выкидывает ошибку, будьте уверены, что в классе модели, вы указали, что IdPostavshika это внешний ключ. Я это сделал примерно так:

```
namespace ASPAzs.Models
{
    public class Azs
    {
        public string FamiliaDirectora { get; set; }
        //[Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        [ForeignKey("postavshik")]
        public int IdPostavshika { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public int IdSotrudnika { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int IdAzs { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("IdPostavshika")]
        public Postavshik postavshik { get; set; }
    }
}
```